Rendering text with a rounded shadow using Jetpack Compose
I want to create a shadow around the text, as in the example
In xml, I did it as indicated below:
<item name="android:shadowColor">@color/black</item>
<item name="android:shadowDx">3</item>
<item name="android:shadowDy">3</item
<item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>

How can I do this in Jetpack Compose?
I used the shadow modifier, but it creates a shadow in the form of a square. It doesn't suit my needs.

In Jetpack Compose, you can add a shadow to each character in Text by using the shadow parameter within TextStyle. This will apply the shadow individually to each character, not as a box around your entire text.
This will make the shadow similar to your XML properties:
Text(
    text = "Your text",
    style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
        color = Color.Black,
        shadow = Shadow(
            color = Color.Black,
            offset = Offset(3f, 3f),
            blurRadius = 2f
        )
    )
)


You might want to use LocalTextStyle.current.copy(...) instead of TextStyle(...) in case there are already any other text style modifications present that should not be overwritten.

Thank you for your suggestion! You're right, your suggestion would be a better approach

Then you should probably [edit] your answer accordingly. :)

I edited it as your suggestion!
